# How to make a localStorage not reset when the app renders?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I have created a localStorage that adds +1 every time the user visits my app. The problem is that every time I refresh the page, the value goes back to 0.

This is my code:

```
  localStorage.setItem('timesVisited', 0);

  useEffect(() => {
      if (localStorage.getItem('timesVisited') < 5) {
      let timesVisited = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('timesVisited'));
      localStorage.setItem('timesVisited', ++timesVisited);
    }
},[])
```

The idea is to make the localStorage sum +1 until it reaches 5 but it keeps on 0. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: That's cause it's related to your browser not your code.

Comment: Is there any workaround for that @ZombieChowder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line will always run and resets any previous value

```js
localStorage.setItem('timesVisited', 0);
```

turn it into

```js
if(!localStorage.getItem('timesVisited')){
  localStorage.setItem('timesVisited', 0)
}
```

Comment: I see that this is the problem. What solution should I apply to fix that?

Comment: @ncesar by adding an if block on top of it

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, if localstorage not set then set 0 otherwise increment

```
 useEffect(() => {
   if (!localStorage.getItem('timesVisited')) {
     localStorage.setItem('timesVisited', 0);
   } else if (localStorage.getItem('timesVisited') < 5) {
     let timesVisited = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('timesVisited'));
     localStorage.setItem('timesVisited', ++timesVisited);
   }
 }, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

If the lines you provided in the component's body, then not only will it be called every time a user visits your app, but every time the component renders.

For the behaviour you're looking for, you should load the value, and set it to 0 if it doesn't exist. You should do this outside of your component, too.

Also, note that localStorage only stores strings, so you'll want to parse what you fetch from it.

```
    const storedValue = localStorage.getItem('timesVisited')
    // localStorage only stores string
    const visitsCount = storedValue ? parseInt(storedValue) : 0

    function myComponent = () => {
        useEffect(() => {
            if(visitsCount >= 5){ 
                return
            }
            localStorage.setItem('timesVisited', ++visitsCount);
        }, [])
    }
```